# Tensorflow installation error (could not find the version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow)

Tags: tensorflow

When I run :

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow
```

This message pops up:

```
could not find the version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow
```

what should I do?

Comment: Which operating system you are using?

Comment: I'm using win 7 (64 bit) OS

Answer (score 1):

This is probably happening because you are using a pip version below 8.3.
In that case, you can install tensorflow using

- For CPU version - `pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-1.7.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl`
- For GPU version - `pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-1.7.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl`

These binaries are for version 1.7 and Python 2.7. You can get the latest wheel URLs from [the official installation guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux#the_url_of_the_tensorflow_python_package).

Comment: OK thank you for your help! ill look forward to install TF now with the code you gave :D

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
conda install pip
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me on Windows 10. Currently, Tensorflow only works with **64-bit** windows, not 32-bit. So, you could create a new 64-bit environment and install tensorflow in it:

```
set CONDA_FORCE_32BIT=
conda create --name name_of_your_created_environment python=3.5
activate name_of_your_created_environment
conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow
```

*Note:
CONDA_FORCE_32BIT=1 sets to a 32-bit environment whilst CONDA_FORCE_32BIT= sets to a 64-bit environment.*